# Get JSON data from edge://policy (chrome://policy) to Angular app

Tags: angular, http, get, microsoft-edge, policy

Every user of Edge Chromium or Google Chrome browser can access page where there are all browser's policies listed: edge://policy (or respectively: chrome://policy). In that place there is a possibility to get JSON file containing all the policies (see attached image).
In my Angular app I need to have access to that file, just to display policies (for example in the table). Is there any possibility to get the data via http client or something?

[image]

Comment: The only way would be for the user to download that json and upload it again in your angular app.

Comment: If this is possible, I don't want to use this browser anymore. This would be a major security issue. Why should a website have access to my policies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this policy to denied access :

urlblocklist='edge://policy/'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#urlblocklist

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).